# eclipse crash on startup

Tags: eclipse, crash

i updated to eclipse juno today by copying it to the folder of former helios version, and it works normally.then i did auto-updates and restart eclipse,but it crashed and cannot be started now.
this is the log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-04-02 17:35:39.393
!MESSAGE 应用程序错误
!STACK 1
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.EBindingService.getPerfectMatch(Lorg/eclipse/jface/bindings/TriggerSequence;)Lorg/eclipse/jface/bindings/Binding;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/ui/internal/keys/BindingService, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) for resolved class, org/eclipse/e4/ui/bindings/EBindingService, have different Class objects for the type org/eclipse/jface/bindings/TriggerSequence used in the signature
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.BindingService.persistToModel(BindingService.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.BindingService.access$1(BindingService.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.BindingService$1.reRead(BindingService.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.BindingPersistence.read(BindingPersistence.java:1284)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.BindingService.readRegistryAndPreferences(BindingService.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.initializeDefaultServices(Workbench.java:2005)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.init(Workbench.java:1387)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$36(Workbench.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$54.run(Workbench.java:2440)
```

Comment: I have had the exact same problem due to multiple versions of `org.eclipse.jface` in my `eclipse/plugins` directory. After deletion of one of those, everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your 'update' process is flawed. You're supposed to either upgrade using the 'Update Manager' or install from scratch. You probably have a broken Eclipse install right now.

Comment: You mean Eclipse's update process is flawed, because even after being around for 8 years they still don't really have one.